# В Android приложении отображается только последний элемент списка

Tags: java, android, циклы

Задача Activity проитерировать список, чтобы каждый элемент отработал по 5 секунд, но при переходе на Activity отрабатывает только последний элемент. Подскажите пожалуйста, что делать и как это можно исправить.

Так же добавлю, что я уже проверил, чтобы приходящий список был целый, а не только последний элемент.

P.S. Ошибок в приложении нет.

```
public class TrainingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public TextView nameAction;
public TextView timerView;
public ProgressBar progressBar;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_training);

    timerView = findViewById(R.id.textTimer);
    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    nameAction = findViewById(R.id.nameAction);

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("one");
    list.add("two");
    list.add("three");

    for (String tmp : list) {
  
        nameAction.setText(tmp);
        CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer
                (5 * 1000L, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long l) {
                progressBar.setMax(5 * 1000);
                timerView.setText("" + l / 1000);
                progressBar.setProgress((int) (l / 1000));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
            }
        };
        timer.start();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Вы, кажется, хотите, чтобы у вас был один таймер, который раз в секунду менял бы что-то на экране и перезапускался бы столько раз, сколько элементов в списке.

Коли так, то вам надо не цикл запустить с множеством таймеров, но стартовать новый таймер, когда завершится предыдущий. Например создайте метод, который будет запускать таймер

Comment: Хорошее решение, могу я еще узнать почему не работает именно мой код?

Comment: Скорее всего все ваши таймеры отрабатывают, просто последний отрабатывает сразу за предыдущими, с разницей в пару миллисекунд. В итоге не успевают отрисоваться изменения предыдущих таймеров. А если и успевают - вы не успеваете их увидеть, т.к. они всего пару миллисекунд отобржаются.